# Jquery - resizeable DIV with child (100% height & width) and dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, draggable

i have a DIV with dynamic content and resize function. 
Here is an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/UsRuh/4/

The problem is the dynamic content.  
Example -> http://jsfiddle.net/UsRuh/5/

It will only work when i set the padding from the `#main` DIV higher. 
Example -> http://jsfiddle.net/UsRuh/6/

Is it possible (only with CSS, no JS!) to resolve this problem?

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background-color:#faf; }

#main {
    position: absolute; top: 18px; left: 18px; width: 384px; height: 157px;
    padding:0px 0px 80px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;}

#scrollDiv {
    background-color:#ccaacc;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: 100%; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="header">Head</div>

    <div style="background-color:#555;"> some dynamic content text text text text <br /> some dynamic content</div>

    <div id="scrollDiv"> some dynamic content width "invisible" scroll<br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text .... ext text </div>

    <div style="background-color:#555;"> some dynamic content text text text text <br /> some dynamic content</div>

</div>
```

**EDIT:** 
If no other solution exists, please tell me.

Comment: `"Is it possible (only with CSS, no JS!)"` - why bother limiting yourself to *CSS only* when you're already using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: I need the fastest solution. The dynamic content comes from php, if i set the high with JS, the DIVs are "jumping"(resizing) when i load my page.

Comment: @Peter: Sorry, but can you explain a little more you problem? i'm not sure I understand quite well.

Comment: Hi diosney, i try to build this example http://jsfiddle.net/UsRuh/25/  without the css work around (padding). The mainproblem is the 100% height from the textarea and the resize function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no CSS-only crossbrowser solutions available.

The only way to achieve it now — to use extra wrappers and `display:table` + `display:table-raw`, so it would look like that: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/UsRuh/28/

The problem still: IE. IE6 and IE7 won't understand `table` values of the `display` property.

So there are only two possible ways to overcome IE:

- use expressions (but it's the same as the use of JS)
- use unsemantic table instead of divs, so it would work everywhere.

That's really a big problem and *table layout* was the only posible solution for a long time. However, in the future (and now in webkit and firefox) we can try to use the flexible box model.

With flexible box model it's realy easy to achieve what you want only with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/UsRuh/29/

And that's why the flexible box model appeared. Too sad, it's availability is still not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one  `div` with dynamic content below scrollable div you make it snap to bottom with absolute positioning. Just make sure parent `div` (`#main`) has relative or absolute positioning.

- Small dynamic content: http://jsfiddle.net/yYwv5/
- Large dynamic content: http://jsfiddle.net/sH8eJ/

Comment: The problem in your solution is that the scroll doesnt work correct. -> http://jsfiddle.net/yYwv5/1/ ... Thanks for the fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a slight change in CSS and can be seen at: http://jsfiddle.net/KuzTB/

I have included a pseudo-class of CSS3: nth-child(n) and applied it on last inner div.

Comment: same problem (like marks solution). Scroll does not work correct -> http://jsfiddle.net/KuzTB/3/

Comment: I have tested it on Chrome, Safari and FireFox. Can you tell me which browser you are using?

Comment: strange, i use the FF too. Here is a screenshot http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/6647/unbenanntgfq.jpg

Comment: can you resize the DIV on FF?